# Removing unnecessary blank spaces in revtex

Tags: revtex

I am writing a paper using revtex4-1 in two column format. I have finished writing the the results and discussion part, but yet to write summary and introduction part. Although I have finished writing the results and discussion part, there remains a large amount of blank spaces in the document here and there in results and discussion section. How can I remove the blank spaces without changing font size, line spacing etc. ?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: My crystal ball isn't working today but my tarot cards suggested that you might be (ab)using floats with the `H` specifier. If that isn't the case then you should post some code instead of trusting in our clairvoyance...

Comment: @campa I am using the H specifier to control float placement. How can that cause the problem, and what is the alternative ?

Comment: `H` sets the float **here**, so if there isn't space enough **here** it is moved to the top of the next page leaving a blank space. Forget you ever heard about `H` and learn to use `htbp` or `htp` and refer to figure numbers.

Comment: `[H]` _by design_ inserts ugly white space into the document, requiring you to move the float by hand, or add more words to fill the space.

Comment: [htbp] really worked